# Авторизация LinkedIn в десктопном приложении

Tags: c#, linkedin

Возник вопрос получить информацию о пользователе, который есть в в сети LinkedIn. Для веб-приложений я делал такое с помощью библиотек, проблем не возникало. А вот как сделать такое для десктопного приложения, сделанного на C# ?
Суть в том, что есть компонент WebBrowser на форме, в котором должна отобразиться форма для логирования в LinkedIn. После успешного логирования получаются данные пользователя, ник, почта, и выводятся, например, в месседж бокс.
Подскажите, как такое реализовать, было б очень хорошо, если с рабочими примерами.
Пишу код на Windows 7, Visual Studio 2012.

Comment: А [это](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/rest-api) пробовали?

Comment: Пробовал разобраться, но как то не пошло. Плюс, возникает вопрос. В некоторых примерах есть redirect_uri. А какой он может буть в локального десктопного приложения, это ж не сайт ??

Comment: Я не спец в linkedin, но думаю, может будет лучше, если вы опубликуете конкретный пример кода с проблемой. Типа "API (ссылка) обещает X, я делаю так (код) и получаю Y, почему?"

Comment: вот я и тоже в этом не спец. пытаюсь что-нибудь искать. нашёл пока вот такой проект, пробую себе подкрутить. https://github.com/alekseynemiro/Nemiro.OAuth.LoginForms

Answer (score 2):

Ну смотрите.
Вот здесь:

```
OAuthToken requestToken = oauthOperations.FetchRequestToken("http://my-callback-url/", null);
```

вместо http://my-callback-url/ указываете адрес сайта, на который OAuth будет присылать токен.
Адрес зарегистрировать можете с помощью:

```
string LoopbackCallback = "http://localhost:{0}/{1}/authorize/";
string url = string.Format(LoopbackCallback, port, "mysite");
var webserver = new HttpListener();
webserver.Prefixes.Add(url);
```

Вместо:

```
Response.Redirect(authorizeUrl);
```

Пишите:

```
Process.Start(authorizeUrl);
url = HandleRequest(webserver.GetContext());
```

Код функции HandleRequest тут: http://pastebin.com/yxB2JsQH

Answer (score 1):

LinkedId использует RESTful формат запросов. Вот ссылка на их документацию:
https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/share-on-linkedin

Это из stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6278603/linkedin-api-in-asp-net

Вот еще интересная вещь: http://www.springframework.net/social-linkedin/

Короче WebRequest/WebResponse в зубы и вперед.

Comment: Ну, вы так одни ссылки набросали. А короткий пример?

Comment: по 3ей ссылке, что дал есть и примеры. С авторизацией и формированием запросов. Готовая библиотека

Comment: ну поповоду первой ссылки, то там больше для веб-приложения, что явно отпадает.
по поводу второй - смотрел эту библиотеку, но откинул, по скольку нашёл другую, где явно попроще можно. но это я смотрел для использования в том же веб-приложении.

Comment: А какая разница? Кодовая база одна и та же. .Net все таки.  По поводу Spring.NET, кудаж еще проще

Comment: ну сейчас посмотрю. но просто я попробовал проект с ссылки моей  github.com/alekseynemiro/Nemiro.OAuth.LoginForms
там нужно написать redirect_uri
я указал свой, с сайта
и вот оно после открытия формы и логирования перекидивает меня на сайт, но никакой информации не выдает

Comment: С OAuth да в этом сложность. У гугла есть хорошие примеры использования их сервисов на C#, с применением OAuth. В т.ч. как потом получать токен после авторизации. К сожалению, уже не помню ссылку. Помню что делалось через простенький прокси сервер.

Comment: попробовал использовать вашу ссылку по спринг. если не ошибся, взял код отсюда http://www.springframework.net/social-linkedin/refdoc/api.html
но при первом же просмотре проблема 
там есть момент - Response.Redirect(authorizeUrl);
а на сколько я знаю Response.Redirect - это поприще ASP.NET

Comment: Комментарий получился слишком большим. Сделал отдельным ответом